# Ionic ion-modal text color is according to device's dark mode not the app's dark mode

Tags: ionic-framework, darkmode, ionic6

I've changed the
`@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)` in `variables.css` to a dark class and I'm checking to change to it with `window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches` in typescript. I also have a toggle to change it inside the app. Everything works fine, except some of `ion-modal` elements (which are inside `ng-template`), like this:

```
<ion-modal>
  <ng-template>
      <ion-label>
        test
      </ion-label>
      <ion-text>
        test
      </ion-text>
  </ng-template>
</ion-modal>
```

they are still obeying the device's dark mode, meaning that when I toggle to light mode inside a device that is set to dark mode, the text color stay white while the modal color turns white, make the text invisible. I don't understand if there is something I'm missing here.

I've tried to fix each of their colors manually as a temporary fix, but that might cause other problems and would make my code dirty. I'd appreciate it if anyone can point to me what I am missing here or what is the correct fix for having them follow my dark mode not the device's. here is my Ionic info:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.17.1
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 6.1.9
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 14.2.6
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 13.2.6
   @angular/cli                  : 14.2.6
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 6.1.0

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI      : 3.5.1
   @capacitor/android : 3.5.1
   @capacitor/core    : 3.5.1
   @capacitor/ios     : 3.5.1

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.15.4
   native-run  : 1.6.0

System:

   NodeJS : v16.15.1
   npm    : 8.12.1
   OS     : Windows 10
```

Comment: You need to handle the ion-text color manually.

Comment: @StackoverBlows yeah I did this as a temporary fix (actually I defined a new variable for text color), but I thought there might be some real answer to this problem that would fix it for all situations and I don't have to do this every time I have some faulty elements. thanks anyways.